# Windows Store App and a WebApi

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I'm having a bit of trouble with my recent Windows Store App and WebApi.

I'm trying to do a login system on it, and I had it working with a Console Application + ASP.NET WebAPI.

Here's the console Application Code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  Console.WriteLine("Insira o username");
  String nome = Console.ReadLine();
  Console.WriteLine("Insira a password");
  String password = Console.ReadLine();

  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49800"); // Variavel global
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

  Users usrlogin = new Users() { Login = nome, Password = password };
  var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/employees/login", usrlogin).Result;

  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
```

Basically, I'm creating a `Users` object and then I send it to my WebApi, which makes all the checking with the DB.

How can I "translate" it to the Windows Store Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The high level approach for the windows store app could be,

- To construct the `Users` object by getting inputs from the app, maybe a text box control
- To send the object to web api

Refer [Consuming Web API from Xaml](http://www.piotrwalat.net/consuming-asp-net-web-api-services-in-a-windows-8-c-xaml-app/). It has a sample implementation of a web api call from windows store app. Hope it helps

Comment: This is what I have at the moment:
http://pastie.org/private/0r6uoeir5zr7ujpbpuxa#13

Though it gives an error on PostAsync, because 2nd command requires a HttpContent.

Comment: Refer [Consuming Web API from Xaml](http://www.piotrwalat.net/consuming-asp-net-web-api-services-in-a-windows-8-c-xaml-app/). It has a sample implementation of a web api call from windows store app. Hope it helps

Comment: Glad it worked. I've edited the answer with links. If you think the answer helped, feel free to mark it as an answer. Have a great day!!